# JAXB: Which elements are marshallable|unmarshallable by default?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, specifications

I *know* that this is specified somewhere, but just can't find it.

Somewhere in the JAXB api docs or spec there must be information about which properties a class must fulfill, so that JAXB can marshal|unmarshal it without the necessity of an JAXB type adapter.

*It was something about `toString()`, the `List` interface, certain ctor signature must fit, and so on ...*

Please point me to a location.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Section 5.4.1 of the JAXB 2.2 specification (JSR-222) talks about the creation requirements:

> Creation
>
> - A value class supports creation via a public constructor, either an
>     explicit one or the default no-arg constructor.
> - A factory method in the package’s ObjectFactory class (introduced in
>     Section 5.2, “Java Package”). The factory method returns the type of
>     the Java value class. The name of the factory method is generated by
>     concatenating the following components:
>
>   - The string constant create.
>   - If the Java value class is nested within another value class,
>       then the concatenation of all outer Java class names.
>   - The name of the Java value class.
>       For example, a Java value class named Foo that is nested within Java
>       value class Bar would have the following factory method signature
>       generated in the containing Java package’s ObjectFactory class:
>       Bar.Foo createBarFoo() {...}

Section 5.5 covers Properties

**Other**

- There is nothing in the JAXB specification regarding `toString()`.